# Correlation matrix and eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, correlation, noise

I have a correlation matrix which has the first 6 eigenvalues substantially greater than the last 11. Also, the last eleven are nearly 1's. Does that mean that the last values symbolize the noise. I am confused why my eigenvalues drop at some point dramatically and remain nearly ones. Something is going on but I cannot wrap my head around.

Comment: I'm confused.  The sum of the eigenvalues is the trace, which is $17$, which is hard to square with what  you say:  6 big numbers plus 11 numbers close to 1 sounds like it's bigger than $17$.  Or do you mean *covariance matrix* instead? In which case, the guess that there are 6 dimensions worth of interesting behavior plus 11 of noise looks like what's going on.

Comment: Covariance and correlation is nearly the same. Just the mean subtracted. I am estimating the covariance (correlation) matrix from samples. I take snapshots of data and do the estimation of covariance (correlation) matrix. Then I look at the eigenvalues of that matrix. The result I see is that I have 6 large eigenvalues and the rest are 1's. Does that mean I can use smaller snapshots to estimate my covariance (correlation) matrix?

Comment: A correlation matrix has rows and columns scaled so that all diagonal entries are equal to 1.  In your case it seems like you have 6 dimensions worth of interesting stuff plus 11 of junk.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Thanks. So can I reduce number of snapshots to estimate my covariance matrix? I have a long stream of data. So I organize it into length M vectors and using those vectors I estimate the covariance matrix. For example, $R=X*X^T$ where $R$ is covariance matrix and X is M length vector out of my data stream . I have no clue how long those vectors should be.

Comment: A next step is often to do an SVD and to project your data vectors onto 6 space.

Comment: I need SVD and got Frobenius norm to be 1.3 when I used those first 6 eigenvalues? I know what 1st or 2nd norm is but Frobenius does not ring the bell. I know that I need to minimize it...